# What level of confidential information can I save in a $_SESSION variable?

Tags: php, session, security, session-variables

Let's think you have a shopping application with credit card payment ability. A user logs in and starts shopping. Is it ok to fetch his credit card number and password from database and save them to a session variable as soon as the user logs in to eliminate the need for future SQL queries in the next steps through which the user is going to complete his payment?

Please describe it when:
a) The connection is not secure
b) The connection is established under SSL security

The credit card application above is an example. I want to have an insight on the security of session variables.

Comment: sessions are stored on you host machine. this does read like a school project.

Comment: I do know that, what about connection, cookies, etc? This is not a school project, I'm trying to understand the level of security of session vars.

Comment: cookies are not sessions

Comment: Storing the CC information in your database is a big security concern in and of itself.

Comment: if the db is on the same host\vm\cluster\what ever as the web server then the data is never passed over a 'public' network

Comment: Indeed, but what about browsers who don't support cookies so use phpsessid? And what about the host's security? And if you post these as an answer with clear explanations I may accept it, you know.

Comment: Why would you want to store the password in the session anyway? And why do you even have the password stored? You only need to store a hash of it to verify it.

Comment: a session id is a file name of the session on your host machine, in of itself useless. fun read on cc storage et al https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/

Comment: As explained, I want to know how secure sessions are. I've never actually done an application that stores passwords to sessions. So my applications are still safe. :)

Comment: i think that's been fully explained to you already

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Dagon says, all session data typically resides **on the server**.

However, there are still a few pitfalls. First off, in many configurations session variables are stored in `/tmp/` and owned by the web server process's owner. In a shared hosting situation, it is conceivable that other users on the shared host manage to access the session data. Second, you can configure your own session handler, e.g. to store session data in a database. In that case, all the security concerns of that implementation have to be taken into account as well.

Best not to store credit card data in the session data; just write it to a safe location and retrieve it by some sensible mechanism (e.g. database lookup) when actually needed.

Answer (score 4):

Even though session variables is stored on the server, the only real security is the session-cookie which if compromised, would allow any other visitor to start the same session,, hence be able to see the page in the same way as the original visitor.

The session-cookie is just a random string generated by PHP, and is viewable in plain text (unless you use SSL) for any "man in the middle" thus making it possible to hijack another persons session.

Storing any kind of sensitive data is in every way a potential security issue, that is why you today need PCI-DSS certified hosting and environment in order to process credit card information. This applies even though you never "store" it on your server, as long as the information flow  through your equipment you will need to be compliant with PCI-DSS regulation.

The reason for this is that it would always be available at some time on the computers memory, and a compromised computer could potentially have malicious software that could identify that data and spread it for bad intentions.

Comment: "_unless you use SSL_" and you use Secure flag for your cookies. No using SSL and accepting connections to port 80 it's also a bad practice (if you really wants to avoid man in the middle attacks)

Comment: Yeah, any non SSL connections made to the same site / domain will recieve the same session-cookie. Thanks for pointing that out.